# Find lines with all tildes

Tags: regex, vim

How can I search for a line in Vim with all `~` chars, e.g.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried `/^\~*$`. Not sure why it s not working.

`/^\~` and `/\~$` do work, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `\+` to find one or more tildes:

```
/^\~\+$
```

Using `*` would find zero or more, and would thus give you all blank lines too.